# bad path address with rewrite-rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

i'm already asked similar question month ago and dt recieve solution for my situation. 
But now i have one important notice for this problem.

i'm running site on local web server. Path of site is http://ikot.
And when i enter adress like "ikot/news" - it's ok
but when i enter ikot/media, it transforms to "http://ikot/media/?level[0]=media&depth=1"

my rewrite rules in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$   /index.php?level[0]=$1&depth=1 [L,QSA]                       
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$   /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&depth=2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$                   /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&depth=3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$      /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&level[3]=$4&depth=4 [L,QSA]
```

the reason of this transformation (ikot/media to ikot/media/[garbage] path) is that i have "media" folder at my site's root folder. And maybe rewrite rule somehow considers, that i want to enter this folder or something like that (but ikot/media leads to media page of site, not to contents of media folder).

Help me pls with this situation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try switching off DirectorySlash. It looks that mod_dir changes yours url and rewrite doesn't work in way you want (first mod rewrite changes it to index.php?... and next mod dir redirects to /media/?... - or something like that).

Adding "DirectorySlash Off" to .htaccess works for me.

If it helps, please read carefully "Security Warning" on that page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: it works! thanks!)
*going to read security notice u mentioned